# jquery mobile: Object [object Object] has no method 'jqmData'

Tags: jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I am relatively new to Jquery and Jquery mobile, I was just trying and tutorial to add Loading animation on the page, I was simply following the code provided in one of the demos. However I am getting the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jqmData'
```

I am using the following code snippet and javascript

```
<button class="show-page-loading-msg ui-btn-right" data-icon="refresh" data-theme="d" data-textonly="false" data-textvisible="true" data-msgtext="Loading..." data-inline="true">Refresh</button>

<script>
window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;
$( document ).on( "click", ".show-page-loading-msg", function() {
var $this = $( this ),
    theme = $this.jqmData( "theme" ) || $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.theme,
    msgText = $this.jqmData( "msgtext" ) || $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.text,
    textVisible = $this.jqmData( "textvisible" ) || $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.textVisible,
    textonly = !!$this.jqmData( "textonly" );
    html = $this.jqmData( "html" ) || "";
$.mobile.loading( "show", {
        text: msgText,
        textVisible: textVisible,
        theme: theme,
        textonly: textonly,
        html: html
});

setTimeout(WL.Client.reloadApp, 5000);
$.mobile.loading( "hide" );
});

</script>
```

The error is pointing to this line in the javascript  `theme = $this.jqmData( "theme" )`
when i debugged on browser console i was able to see the button data values assigned to the $this variable
Please advice,

Comment: Woul also help to understand what is your Worklight version....

Answer (score 0):

if you run the following:

```
console.log($.mobile.version);
```

... and check the console. Does it print out the version? Or does it say it is undefined?

If it is undefined, check if you have correctly referenced jQuery and jQuery mobile libraries, something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, this is what I have currently refrenced

`<link href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js"></script>`

Comment: Ah, try to use jquery version 1.9.1 (which is the one to be used with jQuery Mobile 1.3.1). Simplified jsFiddle is here - http://jsfiddle.net/35hBY/

Comment: Did that still not working :( . Am running it on worklight server, You think that might have something to do with it?

Comment: Hello, I don't know. If this is not running somewhere on the intranet without access to the internet, try to reference the libraries from remote location (as posted). If you can't do this and at least the rest of jQuery mobile is working, you can get the data-theme attribute by calling $this.attr("data-theme"); But I doubt this will be working if jqmData is not. Also, try to grab the whole html page and create jsfiddle or update your post with the full html file.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the inputs, while testing in jfiddle I noticed that if i remove this line `window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;` which is at the begining of the script it was working fine in jfiddle, so I tested the same in my code, that removed the error, however I dont see the Loader, but the next lines to reload the page execute fine

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your script into the 'mobileinit' event handler (or a page event handler), like:

```
    <script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;
        $(document).on('mobileinit', function() {
            // your script
        });
    </script>
    <script src="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js"></script>
```

**NOTE** the sequence of the script

Comment: Hey Thanks for the inputs, this  `window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;` is just used to point the version of jQuery provided by worklight am I right, so if am using my own Jquery verison in the script, can I ignore this line without any implications?

Comment: Yes, and I think you can remove the line and try this way: `window.$ = WLJQ; window.jq = jQuery.noConflict();(function($) { // your script })(jq);`